# Video buffering with embedded Youtube Player on iOS discontinues when video is paused

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using YTPlayerView library (from Google) to embed Youtube Player into my iOS app. I've noticed that buffering of the streaming video stops when the video is paused. Why is this happening and what can be done to fix it?

I'm checking the return value of [self.youTubePlayer videoLoadedFraction] every second, and when the video is paused videoLoadedFraction does not increase over time anymore, but does once the video is played again.

Eventually, what I really want to do is stream two Youtube players at once, so that the user can seamlessly move on to the next video without having to wait for it to load.
Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Might be worth it to open an issue on the project's GitHub page: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues